# Submitting an iMessage Application

Tags: ios, message, imessage

I've been working on an iMessage Application for a while now. This app will solely be an iMessage app, and will have no associated regular iOS Application on the regular app store. I can submit a build of my app just fine (I had to make iMessage App Icons using Apple's [fancy new template](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/resources/), and add this key to the messages extension plist: `MSMessagesExtensionStoreIconName`), but I'm still a little confused as to what I need to provide in iTunes Connect for releasing my iMessage App on the Messages App Store.

1. Do I need to provide an icon in iTunes connect?
2. Do I need to provide
   any screenshots?
3. Do I even need to touch the actual application
   (not the extension) in Xcode?

If anyone can clarify this or provide I link to some documentation (I can't find any) it'd be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, did you figure out why in the first place there's a need to create that key? And what value did you add? I'm unsure about what I might have done wrong to get this error. Thanks if you have any thoughts on this.

Comment: @Simon you should add the following key to your messages extension Plist: MSMessagesExtensionStoreIconName - the value should be a string that you would like to appear in the app drawer as the label under your app's icon. I'm not sure if it can be more than one word, but I would try a very short string first and see the result.

Comment: Thanks a bunch Alex, that should help! Only now I actually get what the key is really referring to.

Comment: for creating icon you can prefer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39379692/missing-148x110-imessage-icon/40771537#40771537

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so I did a bit more digging and these are my results. I gathered all this by looking at the pages for some of Apple's iMessage Apps on the actual App Store. You can view a photo below, or check out [this link](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/smileys/id1127555487?mt=8).

[image: Smileys on the App Store]

1. Nothing needs to happen to the app part of your messages extension in Xcode. You don't need to provide icons, change the plist, write any code, etc.
2. In iTunes Connect, you need to provide a description, keywords, screenshots and optional preview video. In addition, you need to provide an iTunes connect (square, 1024x1024) icon for display on the App Store. It looks like users have the ability to download iMessage apps from both the regular App Store and the dedicated iMessage Apps store, much like for Apple Watch apps.

If anything I said here is incorrect (this is mostly speculation) then please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Apple is not ready yet. You cannot submit apps for iOS 10 yet. Apple will send you an email when they are ready. (like this one from last year) [image: apple email]

I think this will work like Apple Watch apps and the Apple Watch app store.

Comment: Ok thanks, I bet you're right. I'd accept your answer but I did a bit more digging and found more info about what you're supposed to submit, so I'll make my own answer.

Comment: @AlexWulff, that app made by Apple itself. Apple gives itself and some companies (like Adobe, Microsoft) an ability to publish app's with latest SDK

Answer (score 2):

This can happen even in Xcode 8 GM.

You'll get this error if you submit the app without a 1024x768 app icon for the iMessage extension, or if you've provided the wrong size.

Just add the required icon, clean your build, compile and resubmit. That should fix the problem.

Comment: Nailed it!  This error will occur if you provide an icon even 1 or 2 pixels different to 1024x768.