# missing 148x110 iMessage icon

Tags: ios, xcode, imessage

I am trying to post an app that supports messaging to itunesconnect using Xcode.  Whenever I try to post the file, I get the error, "Missing app icon.  The bundle dosn't contain an iMessage app icon.  iMessage app icons must be 148x100 pixels in .png format".

I don't see a place to put in the file.  Where should I put it?

Answer (score 2):

The image that you are adding in iMessage should be size as mention in Assets. **"missing 148x110 iMessage icon"** means you are missed 2x image of imessage icon of  **ipad pro 74*55** **pt** because

> **2*(74*55) == 148*110**

You have to add above size image at **2x section of "ipad pro 74*55"**

[image]

> You can change the size of the exist icon by below steps:-

```
i)Open Preview 
ii)Select Adjust size 
iii)Enter width & Height 148*110 or according to other required sizes.
iv)Place images to appropriate places in Assets section.
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There should be a place in the Asset Catalog to upload a 74x55 icon for the iPad pro. It's in the second row of icons.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Assets.xcassets -> iMessage App Icon Add icon of 148x100 size under 74×55pt.