# Troubles submitting my app in xCode

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

What do I do if this pops up in xCode?

iTunes Store operation failed.
Missing App Icon. The bundle doesn’t contain an iMessage app icon. iMessage app icons must be 180x135 pixels in .png format.

Comment: Probably a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39379692/1531971

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to your assets file.
2. Select your AppIcon assets folder.
3. Ensure that the required asset is present & is of the correct size/format.
4. If it's not listed, drag and drop 180x135 .png into the app icon folder.

[image: app icon assets]